# Error 404 en github pages

Tags: html, error404, tailwind, github-pages

Tengo una pagina que estoy intentando subir a github pages, pero al abrir el link me sale error 404: https://maydenot.github.io/passwordgenerator.github.io/, si le agrego al link el public/, que es la carpeta donde se encuentra mi archivo index.html el javascript y css, funciona y carga bien https://maydenot.github.io/passwordgenerator.github.io/public/. Pero no se como hacer para que github pages directamente me mande a la carpeta public, creo que es muy feo e incomodo tener que estar escribiendo manualmente la carpeta al link. Alguna solucion?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Dejo una imagen de la estructura de mi proyecto, en la cual dentro de la carpeta public se puede ver como se encuentra el archivo html. Necesito que el link que se suba a github pages contenga la carpeta public, ya que como puse en el mensaje anterior es la unica manera que encontre para arreglar el error 404

Comment: Es decir que este link https://maydenot.github.io/passwordgenerator.github.io/ que es el original de github pages pase a ser este https://maydenot.github.io/passwordgenerator.github.io/public/, necesito  saber como se cambia ese link

Comment: Revisaste [lo que respondieron](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/21853#discussioncomment-3234547) en la Comunidad de Github? (desde esa respuesta en adelante)

Comment: @padaleiana gracias por tu tiempo, lamentablemente no me funciono, pero ya lo solucioné cambiando el archivo html a las rama principal en vez de tenerlo dentro de la carpeta public